# Validate a profile field

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

In buddypress I've added a field to profile named `zip code` with type of `number`.

What I need is to validate/cleanup this field before saving data into db, does buddypress support doing this? Is there any buddypress action/filter which let's run my custom validation for this field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function myvalidator($retval, $field){
    // $field->field_id <- from wp_bp_xprofile_fields table 
    //                     find id for your field
    // $field->value    <- this is the value you need to validate
    //                     (make sure $field->field_id is correct
    // $field->user_id

    if (/* valid */){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

    // for other field_ids return $retval
}


add_filter( 'xprofile_data_is_valid_field', 'myvalidator', 10, 2 )
```